# Buscar un objeto dentro de un array con mongoose

Tags: javascript, api, express, rest, mongoose

Estoy creando una api  en *mongoose* y *nodejs* para el siguiente *json* que tiene un `array` el cual tiene unos objetos adentro para poder realizar el `get_id` de mi api, alguien me puede ayudar, es decir necesito obtener el documento que contenga el id especifico para buscarlo y no se el código en *mongoose* para este proceso.

```
    {"_id": "5e181fed9fc1883a69797e3a", "hotels":[
        {
        "name" : "Hotel Emperador",
        "stars" : 4,
        "price" : 1596,
        "imagen" : "https://i.ibb.co/RHYqxjL/hotel1.jpg",
        "id": 1
        },

        {
        "name" : "Hotel Sonesta",
        "starts": 4,
        "price" : 2400,
        "imagen" : "https://i.ibb.co/kx06vbZ/hotel2.jpg",
        "id": "sonesta"
        }
        ,
        {

        "name" : "Hotel Soratama",
        "stars" : 3,
        "price" : 1000,
        "imagen" : "https://i.ibb.co/hx0Txk6/hotel3.jpg",
        "id": "3"
        }}
```

Necesito la siguiente salida cuando haga el `find` de algún documento con el id.

```
{
    "name" : "Hotel Emperador",
    "stars" : 4,
    "price" : 1596,
    "imagen" : "https://i.ibb.co/RHYqxjL/hotel1.jpg",
    "id": 1
    }
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola bienvenido a SO en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta

Comment: disculpen ya lo traduje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si entiendo bien la estructura... el caso de uso podría ser por ejemplo una colección en donde listas los hoteles disponibles en cada ciudad... por lo que tu colección real tiene más de un documento, y cada documento contiene un array bajo `hotels`. Algo así?

dado que tienes una colección en donde los elementos tienen la estructura

```
db={
  comercios: [
    {
      _id: "5e181fed9fc1883a69797e3a",
      hotels: [
        {
          name: "Hotel Emperador",
          stars: 4,
          price: 1596,
          imagen: "https://i.ibb.co/RHYqxjL/hotel1.jpg",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Hotel Sonesta",
          starts: 4,
          price: 2400,
          imagen: "https://i.ibb.co/kx06vbZ/hotel2.jpg",
          id: "sonesta"
        },
        {
          name: "Hotel Soratama",
          stars: 3,
          price: 1000,
          imagen: "https://i.ibb.co/hx0Txk6/hotel3.jpg",
          id: "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(hago presente que en el texto de tu pregunta tienes un array sin cerrar)

La búsqueda por el id de un documento anidado se haría con un pipeline de agregación:

```
db.comercios.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$hotels"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "hotels.id": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Eso entrega

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e181fed9fc1883a69797e3a",
    "hotels": {
      "id": 1,
      "imagen": "https://i.ibb.co/RHYqxjL/hotel1.jpg",
      "name": "Hotel Emperador",
      "price": 1596,
      "stars": 4
    }
  }
]
```

<kbd>[MongoFiddle](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aFwGBZhiRJt)</kbd>

Con mongoose se hace casi igual salvo que en vez de `db.comercios` sería directamente la colección de Mongoose: `mongooseData.aggregate(...)`

Si quieres mapear ese array para que ingrese un nivel más de profundidad (pero ojo, al hacer eso pierdes el verdadero `_id`) agregas al pipeline el reemplazo del objeto raíz:

```
db.comercios.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$hotels"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "hotels.id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$hotels"
    }
  }
])
```

Y con eso llegamos a lo que quieres:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "imagen": "https://i.ibb.co/RHYqxjL/hotel1.jpg",
    "name": "Hotel Emperador",
    "price": 1596,
    "stars": 4
  }
]
```

(el find sobre la colección siempre devuelve un arreglo, pero en este caso sólo contiene tu el hotel que buscabas)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda !!!! agregando la estructura adiccional funciona correactamente.

Comment: tengo una consulta un poco tonta, a que te refieres con colección en mongoose, es schema que exporto de los modelos es decir:

module.exports = mongoose.model('hotel', mainSchema); 

o en que parte del proyecto se define esta coleccion, es que entiendo que es db.collections.agreggate(), pero en ninguna parte de mi proyecto defino la coleccion de mi db. la duda es porque cambio el esquema a algo como esto.

[https://mongoplayground.net/p/e7eWm4rvVEa]

Comment: Mongoose es un odm, provee una capa de abstracción sobre la implementación específica de la base de datos. No tengo idea si en la actualidad tiene sintaxis distinta al repl de mongo.